# CodeIgniter FTP connection error

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am trying to connect to my FTP server using CodeIgniter FTP Class. What I want to do is to just display a success message when the connection is successful and display an error message if an error occurs. I have found that the `$this->ftp->connect()` function returns `1` for successful connection. But when an error occurs it takes me to the error page instead of displaying the error message.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$this->load->library('ftp');
$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug']    = TRUE;
if ($this->ftp->connect($config)) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "error!";
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can handle this error will be really helpful.

Comment: Who is your ftp provider? make sure to add $config['port']     = ;

Comment: @Ilan Hasanov: my ftp provider is orgfree.com and my code is using the default port 21 as $config['port'] is not defined.

Comment: And you are successfully connected to your FTP before with the same credentials? is this SFTP or FTP?

Comment: I am connecting using ftp. The error occurs in the event of wrong password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the error message just by turning off the debug option.

```
$config['debug'] = FALSE;
```